# Docker container for Laravel: PHP 7.x on CentOS 7.x

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker, containers

My application is based on *Laravel framework*, and I need to build a *Docker container* with these specifications:

- CentOS/RHEL 7.x
- PHP 7.x
- PHP extensions:

  - OpenSSL
  - PDO
  - Mbstring
  - Tokenizer
  - XML

But the problems are:

- The official PHP image on the DockerHub is based on *Ubuntu*, but I rather have PHP on RHEL/CentOS instead of Ubuntu.
- The latest PHP version on CentOS official Yum repositories is *5.4.16* which is lower than the version Laravel requires. Based on distrowatch.com, it seems like RHEL also still has the same old version of PHP on its repositories.
- I cannot trust unofficial images, so the solution should be based on official images only.
- I want to use this container in my production environment, so I rather rely on trusted resources instead of third-party repositories like Webtatic.

Is there any way to have the latest version of PHP on a Docker container based on CentOS? For example, is it possible to make an image based on both [CentOS](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/) and [PHP](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) official images?

---

Sorry if my question sounds stupid, I am still new to Docker and after reading the documents and a number of articles online I haven't found my answer yet.

Comment: You can pull down official CentOS image first and on top of it you can install php 7 and other php libraries using yum. Then  you can commit the the resulting container as a new image and use it for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.

The problem is that the highest available version of PHP on official RHEL/CentOS Yum repositories is 5.4.16. It is possible to install these packages by adding Webtatic repository or compiling from the source, but this shouldn't be safe for the production.

Answer (score 1):

I followed following steps and successfully created [CentOS](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/) image with php 7.0.

Pull down and run CentOS image with interactive mode.

```
docker run -it centos
```

I followed these steps mentioned at [webtatic](https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/) to setup `php7`. To install, first you must add the Webtatic EL yum repository information corresponding to your CentOS/RHEL version to yum

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

To install PHP 7

```
yum install php70w php70w-opcache
```

Install packages by

```
yum install OpenSSL PDO Mbstring Tokenizer xml zip unzip curl
```

I additionally added `zip unzip curl` as they are required to install composer.

Exit out from container by typing `exit` and list down available containers.

```
docker ps -a
```

copy the container id and commit it as a new image by using following command.

```
docker commit -m "setup centos image with php7.0 and composer" -a "Your Name" 2b252ba66277 yourname/centos-php7.0-composer
```

list down available images and you'll see the newly created image.

```
docker image ls
```

Run the newly created image

```
docker run -it yourname/centos-php7.0-composer
```

**Edit**

You can also pull down [gayansanjeewa/centos-php7.0-composer](https://hub.docker.com/r/gayansanjeewa/centos-php7.0-composer/) which I have created with these steps.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I want to use this Docker container in my production environment, so I rather rely on an official package from a trusted source.

Is there any other solution except using third-party repositories like Webtatic?

Comment: It seems like its not possible for the moment as php7 is not yet supported by centos. I googled some more and result is same. This leave with either you use image such as Ubuntu or get the support of a third party package.

Comment: Thank you, so there there seems to be no way of adding two images and build a new one. For example is there any way to make an image based on both PHP and CentOS official images on Docker Hub?